# Show that $\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} +\frac{c}{a} + \frac{d}{b}\le-12$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$ be non-zero, pairwise different real numbers such that $ \frac{a}{b} +\frac{b}{c} +\frac{c}{d} + \frac{d}{a}=4$ and   $ac=bd$  .
Show that $\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} +\frac{c}{a} + \frac{d}{b}\le-12$ and that $-12$ is the maximum.

I simplified the inequality to prove: $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\le -12ac$

But I am not sure what to do next.
Hints and solutions would be appreciated.

Taken from the 2018 Pan African Math Olympiad http://pamo-official.org/problemes/PAMO_2018_Problems_En.pdf

Comment: Your simplification cannot be right as for $a,c$ both negative or positive we would have$ a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2< 0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hint.

Prove that $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{d}{c}+\frac{c}{d}\leq-2$$ or
$$\frac{b}{c}+\frac{d}{a}=\frac{a}{d}+\frac{d}{a}\leq-2$$ and use 
 $$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{d}{b}=\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}\right)\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{d}{a}\right).$$
A full solution.

Let $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}>0$ and $\frac{b}{c}+\frac{d}{a}>0$.

Thus, by AM-GM $$4=\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}\right)+\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{d}{a}\right)=\left(\frac{d}{c}+\frac{c}{d}\right)+\left(\frac{a}{d}+\frac{d}{a}\right)\geq2+2=4,$$
which gives $c=d$ and $a=d$, which is impossible.

Thus, one of the expressions $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}$ or $\frac{b}{c}+\frac{d}{a}$ is negative.

Let $u=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}<0$.

Thus, $$u=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{d}{c}+\frac{c}{d}\leq-2$$ and we need to prove that
$$u(4-u)\leq-12$$ or
$$(u+2)(u-6)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

The equality occurs for $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=-2$, $\frac{b}{c}+\frac{d}{a}=6$ and $ac=bd.$

Easy to see that it's possible, which says that $-12$ is a maximal value.

Comment: Whoa, nice! I kept thinking that hint wasn't enough (or helpful), until I figured it out.

Comment: Doesn’t the two inequalities you gave contradict the first equation I gave because it must equal $4$ but assuming your inequalities are right it would have to be $\le-4$ or am I missing something?

Comment: @Tyrone I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = \frac{a}{b},\,v=  \frac{b}{c},$ then $\frac{c}{d}=\frac{1}{u},\,\frac{d}{a}=\frac{1}{v}$ we get $u+v+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}=4,$ and
$$P = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} + \frac{c}{a} + \frac{d}{b} = \left(u+\frac{1}{u}\right)\left(v+\frac{1}{v}\right).$$
Now see $u,v$ can't satisfied $uv > 0.$ Indeed if $u > 0,\,v>0$ then
$$4 = u+\frac{1}{u}+v+\frac{1}{v} \geqslant 2 + 2 =4.$$
Equality occur when $u=v=1$ (contradiction the distinct numbers).

If $u<0,\,v<0$ replace $(u,v)$ by $(-x,-y)$ with $x>0,\,y>0$ then
$$4 = -\left(x+y+\frac 1 x + \frac 1 y\right)< 0 . $$
Thefore $uv < 0,$ now
$$P = -12 + \frac{(u+1)^2(v+1)^2}{uv}-2\left(u+v+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}-4\right) \leqslant -12.$$

See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h216465) or [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h593098p3517320)